# AngularJS SPA Architecture

Tags: angularjs, architecture

I'm making an SPA and 'm really struggling with the correct architecture to get it to work. So I'll outline the details here, then the structure and problems. If someone can show me the correct way to layout the process, it would be really helpful.

SPA Details:
An accounting program where visitors get full access to the site without authentication and can use  to change various data. It is not saved unless they sign up for an account. Users cannot see any information from other user's accounts.

SPA Structure:
Before sign up or authentication:

- A few JS objects are stored in a service (StartService): accData, accCompanies{} These hold all data to be manipulated
- Another service (FunctionsService) depends on StartService and holds all functions since they are used over multiple controllers
- The Functions service is injected to the controllers and $scope variables made for each function in the service.

On signup:

- The objects stored in StartService are sent to server as new account data.

On login:

- The objects in the user's account are retrieved from server and put into StartService.

The user can then click a save button which sends StartService data to their account (the same process as the one on signup)

Problems and Questions:

- I can't figure out how to get the 2-way data binding to work between the two services, controllers and views.
- Do I need to change the structure? For example, one service instead of 2, data in json file instead of in service, use only one controller and move functions to this controller?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend a framework just as angularjs2, which gives you structure to your SPA project. you do dependency injection and work with type script which is type safe. Here is a tutorial you can follow about how to deal with RESTful communication:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

to deal with the routing within the SPA have a look at this answer:

[angularjs2 SPA - how to change gulp task to prevent cannot get /page error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614942/angularjs2-spa-how-to-change-gulp-task-to-prevent-cannot-get-page-error/35632171#35632171)

i personally prefer to use http.post (from angular2/http) over window.fetch as i found it easier dealing with cors issues.

in terms of the data transfer, i would recommend you sending the registration data to your backend (via a json POST) and the backend sending you a jwt (a json token) which you use to authenticate each following request.

i would further recommend using GET (returning a json) to get all the information you need to display the user specific information on each page.

let me know if you need more details.